# mySQL time incorrect

Tags: mysql, timezone

> EDIT: I sheepishly fixed this my restarting mysqld. Sorry for wasing people's time

Hi,

My server's time is set to GMT.  When I run "date" in ssh I get

> Sun Sep 27 23:36:39 BST 2009

However "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" in mySQL returns

> 2009-09-27 15:36:39

and "SELECT @@global.time_zone" returns

> SYSTEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting mySQL allowed it to use the servers updated timezone

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything in the error log?

You could have a problem similar to the one in this thread:

```
081113 15:27:16 [ERROR] Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone
```

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/215197